# How to restore data from Ubuntu if it doesn't load?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, restore

I have a notebook with two installed OS, Ubuntu 14 and Windows 10. Recently notebook had fallen, and I've stucked with problem with my hard drive. Each time when I try turn on notebook, I have the blue screen of death with problem Critical_process_died only. But I need to restore Ubuntu data.

What can I do in this case? Is it possible to restore Ubuntu data?

Comment: Blue screen usually points to a Windows problem. When does it occur? can you see any boot menu? have you tried booting from a live-CD/-USB and copying the data to an external drive, yet?

Comment: Get a [Sata to usb connector](http://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-SATA-Drive-Adapter-Cable/dp/B00HJZJI84/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1439671602&sr=1-1&keywords=sata+to+usb)  and a new hard drive. Install Ubuntu onto the new hard drive, connect old hard drive to the working Ubuntu with that connector, copy over the files, and call it a day. If you plan on getting windows onto the new drive, install windows first, then ubuntu

Comment: @Fiximan : the problem has occured after falling down the notebook. I don't see any boot menu, except BIOS. And I haven't tried booting.

Comment: @Serg : thank you, I'll try it, fortunately I have sata to usb connector. And don't you know, does some other method of data restoration (without new hard drive) exist? Maybe it is possible to do something like Ubuntu boot record restoration? I'm the Ubuntu newbie, so excuse me for possible mistakes.

Comment: Sorry for using bad wording: by boot menu, I meant `grub` or whichever you use for selecting which OS to boot.

Comment: @Fiximan : unfortunately, there aren't any types of boot menu.

Comment: @JohnTaylor There is actually [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) . But I'm not familiar with it, never used it, hence cannot say if it's effective or not

Comment: @Serg : are you sure that the method with sata to usb connector works in principle?

Comment: How far can you get when booting from a live CD (use your Ubuntu installation CD or USB, respectively and use the "Try ubuntu" option)?. If you can get that to run, you can mount your hard disk and copy any file to an external USB drive (even from the Windows partition). If you cannot get that far, you have severe damages in your hardware and should put the hard drive into another machine or use @Serg's method..

Comment: @JohnTaylor just like Fiximan suggested, boot the live cd or usb first, see if you can mount your existing hard drive. If you can and can see the files there, use the sata/usb connector method. Personal opinion - hard drives are cheap nowadays , compared to the past, so if you have opportunity to just make your laptop working again - why not ?

Comment: @Serg : does this method provide possibility of data copying even without Ubuntu installation?

Comment: @JohnTaylor Technically yes, you can copy over the data to the drive. But what about your old drive ? If your old hard drive doesn't boot, how do you work on it ? You could in theory use `dd` or `clonezilla` to just copy over your partitions to new drive, but IMHO its easier and less troublesome. For instance, I've got new SSD. What I did is simply install  Ubuntu to my new SSD and copy over files from old HDD. That's all. Of course, I'd need to spend some time to set up programs and settings the way I like, but it's a minor inconvenience